# Need help in Installing JRE?

Tags: installation, java

i have to install JRE Programmability if the System does not have JRE, i had dected JRE is installed in the system or not, but i have no idea how to install JRE programmtically, some people said you can use installer, but i donot know how to use installer for this purpose i searched in sun documnet, installing JRE in slient mode, there's also i donot know how to use that command iie.fing.edu.uy/ense/asign/…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run your Java program, you can do that without installing the JRE, that its, you can run the application in a computer without JRE, we do that every day.

The way is to deploy you application with an embedded JRE and use a script (.bar, .sh) to execute you application using the embedded JRE. So your application is self-contained and no requires external JRE. You need to copy the entire JRE folder into your application and start removing unused files using the test-error approach. You can also decrease the file sizes removing not needed classes, like in rt.jar (you can decompress, remove unused classes and zip again).

The problem with this approach is that you are violating the Oracle/SUN JRE distribution policy as you are distributing a JRE with fewer files. If the application is for internal use, I think it's OK, if you want to redistribute the application, you are in trouble.

Another question is how to install the JRE by code, you can try to ship the JRE with your application, using an installer detect if JRE is already installed and install it id needed. Doing that in Java code is not trivial, you can use `Runtime` to exec external programs...

Do not rely on `JAVA_HOME`as is not actively used nowadays.

Example:
Say you application name is 'A', you folder structure can look like:

```
A
|-> Run.bat
|- jre
   |- bin
   |- lib
|- lib
   |-> A.jar
```

You application main class is Main.java in package a. Your `Run.bat`can look like `START "" jre\bin\javaw.exe -cp lib\A.jar a.Main`

You only are calling the embedded jre in `jre` folder, by calling the `bin\javaw.exe` and passing the jar and main class. The `jre` folder can content and entire JRE as copied from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\` (Windows 7).

Comment: @David olivan Ubieto:this what i needed, i tried today to embed JRE, but i was failed in my research, i used Launch4j, pls tell me , how to embed JRE with my application, i already copied JRE folder and pasted it in src folder

Comment: You need to copy the jre folder into you app folder, create a script that launches the embedded jre with you application jars. Assume jre is JRE folder and you application jars is in lib, you need (Windows): START "" jre\bin\javaw.exe -cp lib\jar1.jar;lib\jar2.jar ApplicationMainClass

Comment: @David Olivan Ubieto: Still i m confused , can you share me any tutorial are sample with screenshot so that i can get even better, because i was confused how to create those scripts

Comment: @David Olivan Ubieto: i had Created Run.bat file, now tell what i have to do, i mean shall i run that jar file in a Machine where JRE not installed, and can i get output there

Comment: @David: Actaully , i had followed all your steps, arranged package as you said created jar file in lib folder

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh put your application, jre and Run.bat as explained. Put the above line in Run.bat. You only need to execute/invoke Run.bat in order to execute you application with the embedded JRE.

Comment: @David: If i clicked the jar under lib folder, will it gives the me output in all system irrespective of the presence of JRE

Comment: You need to execute/click Run.bat in order to execute your application with the embedded JRE. If you click the jar file under \lib, depending on the computer configuration (has JRE, associated with jar files...) and the jar configuration (has manifest indicating the main class), could execute your application with the computer default's JRE.

Comment: @David:This is my Run.bat file content START "" jre\bin\javaw.exe -cp lib\
MyAppj.jar com.MyApp

Comment: @David: when i ran this Run.bat file, i got this Error, can you pls help me Windows can't find jre\bin\javaw.exe Make Sure you typed the name correctly and then try again

Comment: Can you verify jre\bin\javaw.exe exists? jre\bin\java.exe also works, but opens a console window that normally is ugly.

Comment: @David: yes, that file is available too..,

Comment: This is a problem invocating a program within a .bat file in Windows, so it is out of the scope. I can't decide the problem you are having, but this must works as is only a .bat script calling a program un a relative path.

Comment: David: Actually, what i did is i had created a swing hello World program, i exported a jar of that program in eclipse using Export Wizard , then stored in a lib folder and then i had included the JRE6 folder in my application, and i created a Batch file as shown i above

Comment: My Run.bat look like:
SET _CLASSPATH=lib\X.jar
START "" jre\bin\javaw.exe -Xms32M -Xmx256M -cp "%_CLASSPATH%" com.util.Launcher

Comment: The _CLASSPATH variable is used to set the application jars easily and the used in -cp %CLASSPATH%, but you can user -cp lib\MyJar.jar instead, is equivalent. The above script is Ok, put in two lines please:) (SET _CLASSPATH mind the blank)

Answer (score 1):

If you can have a web based solution you can use deployjava

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Comment: How can i use this method installLatestJRE() - Triggers the installation of the latest JRE , Because when i call this method, it says method undefined, so tell me from which package i have to import it

Comment: @Sankar, you need to embed the script in a webpage and call the relevant method.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds : Oh, How can i use this, Because My Application is a Desktop Application

Comment: deployJava.js can be used to deploy Java Web Start (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) applications.  JWS can launch rich clients (e.g. Swing based) from a web site onto the desk-top.