# Packaging a jre with my application

Tags: c++, windows, java-native-interface, java

My application contains an c++ exe file which invokes a java program using JNI, thus requiring jvm.dll. However, I want my application to ship with its own embedded jre but after I copy the jre6 folder found in JAVA_HOME and added it to my installer, it fails to run the program(Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries), when I use dependency walker on jvm.dll, it says that it can't find gpsvc.dll, IEShims.dll and sysntfy.dll. After I tried copying those dlls to the same folder as jvm.dll, dependency walker tells me that gpsvc.dll andsysntfy.dll is 64 bit where it should be x86. Problem is, those were the only dlls on my system, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may download the required dll's from the appropriate sites, i.e. from [this one](http://www.dll-download-system.com/).

Comment: Ok I manage to find sysntfy.dll and dependency walker just throws an error for gpsvc.dll; I read online that gpsvc.dll only comes in x64 versions, what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, it's not, cause it's Microsoft System Policy Client library. You may get it from http://www.dll-download-system.com/home/g-dlls-not-system-/gpsvc.dll/details.html

Answer (score 2):

The Java virtual machine consists of much more than just `jvm.dll`. You'll need to redistribute the whole JVM package and install that on a user's machine instead of just adding `jvm.dll` to your own application.

It will probably be much easier to require your users to download and install the JVM themselves before installing your application. If you really want to redistribute the JVM with your application, you'll need to find documentation on Oracle's website on what the exact license for that is and on how to do it. Look at [this paragraph](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html#redistribution) of the JDK 6 readme, for example.

It's not as simple as copying `jvm.dll` and other libraries that it depends on.

Comment: Actually, I tried copying the entire jre6 directory according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380778/need-help-in-installing-jre and http://www.dobysoft.com/products/nativej/help/html/advanced/bundling.html ... if that is not redistributing the whole jvm package, what is? are there specific steps that I can follow?

Comment: On Windows, when you install the JRE, it also writes things to the registry. Just copying the JRE directory isn't enough to install it on Windows. You'll need to run the JRE installer.